# Calling second-level function from the second level in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, scope

I have the following code structure:

```
class Test
  def self.test
    def something
      return 'test'
    end
    @test = something()
    print(@test)
  end
end
```

If I try to run this code, Ruby gives me this error:

`test.rb:33:in`test': undefined method `something' for Test:Class (NoMethodError)`

How can I call this function from within the given scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope you are referring to is that of the class - `Test`. The method `something` is actually getting defined as the `instance method` of the class `Test`. You cannot really invoke an instance method from a class scope, hence the error.